# Android: My game keeps starting from the beginning if the view orientation changes

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [problem while changeing the orientation in android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5263346/problem-while-changeing-the-orientation-in-android-app)

I have a card game app I'm working on.  When I flip the android device, switching from landscape to portrait (or vice verse), my card game starts from the beginning.

Every time the android device gets flipped, it calls the create method.  I'm assuming it is creating a new intent?  Is their anyway to stop this? Can it keeps the same intent if the device is flipped?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Android is re-creating your Activity to give you an opportunity to plug in a new layout or whatever orientation-specific handling you need.  You can force your activity to stick in a particular orientation with the manifest entry below.

```
    <activity android:name=".MyActivity"  android:screenOrientation="portrait"       android:configChanges="orientation" ...>
```

For more details on these attributes see:  http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html